# DevExpress XtraRichEdit Clear Header

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-word, devexpress

I am working with DevExpress 2012 controls on VB 2010.  I have a richtext edit control that serves as a Microsoft Word replacement.  I am loading a Word Document that contains a header.  I need to clear that header and re-create it with new data. I know how to insert a new header with data on a new document, but I don't know how to clear the existing header.  I don't find a way to do it.  The following code is not working.  Any Ideas?

```
 Dim headerSection As Section = devWordControl.Document.Sections(0)
 Dim subDoc As SubDocument = headerSection.BeginUpdateHeader(HeaderFooterType.First)

 If headerSection.Margins.Left <> 170 Then
     headerSection.Margins.Left = 170
 End If

 If headerSection.Margins.Right <> 130 Then
     headerSection.Margins.Right = 130
 End If

 subDoc.SelectAll()
 subDoc.Delete(subDoc.Range)
 headerSection.EndUpdateHeader(subDoc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the following code snippets which works fine to me:

```
Sub InsertHeader_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs)
    Dim firstSection As Section = richEditControl1.Document.Sections(0)
    Dim hDoc As SubDocument = firstSection.BeginUpdateHeader()
    hDoc.InsertText(hDoc.CreatePosition(0), "Header")
    firstSection.EndUpdateHeader(hDoc)
End Sub

Sub ChangeHeader_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs)
    Dim firstSection As Section = richEditControl1.Document.Sections(0)
    Dim hDoc As SubDocument = firstSection.BeginUpdateHeader()
    hDoc.Delete(hDoc.Range)
    hDoc.InsertText(hDoc.CreatePosition(0), "New Header")
    firstSection.EndUpdateHeader(hDoc)
End Sub
```

Comment: The result I am getting is that the header is being created twice because the first one was not removed, so they overlap

Comment: @D.Bermudez sounds strange... I believe you should report this issue directly to [DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)